# Material autocomplete is not working with post API in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am sending a **post request** with two parameters i.e. `pubid and pubdate` on **keypress eventchanged in angular** now I am looking to get the **Autocomplete** data after post request for the `Title` field. but autocomplete does not work.

**JSON data**

```
 [{
     "ID": "44",
     "Title": "Saturn"
 }]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  filter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
  this.searchField.valueChanges

    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map((val) => {
           this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/articles/articleslistData', { pubid: '3',pubdate: "2021-01-13" }).subscribe({
            next: data => {
               console.log(data);

            },
            error: error => {
                this.errorMessage = error.message;
                console.error('There was an error!', error);
            }
        })
      })
  )
    }
```

}

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field   class="input-text js-input">
<input type="text"   placeholder="Articles" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="searchField" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [panelWidth]="600">
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredArticle | async" [value]="option.Title">
                        {{option.Title}}
 </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```